# INNER JOIN AND LIMIT INNER TABLE BY 1 AND ORDERBY ID

Tags: php, mysql

This query returns no records, can someone help me rectify what I'm doing wrong?  I want the inner table to fetch only one row, (i.e. I want the left table to first orderby ID DESC and then LIMIT 1, fetch the first result in ascending order).

```
$query = "select fsp_issue_log.ISSUE_SERIAL_NUM , fsp_issue_log.STATUS, fsp_issue_log.DATECREATED, fsp_issue_log.ASSIGNEDTO, fsp_issue_log.ORG
 , fsp_issue_log.SEVERITY
 , fsp_issue_log.DESCRIPTION
 , fsp_ticket_hist.COMMENTS
FROM fsp_issue_log 
JOIN  
 ( SELECT COMMENTS 
     FROM fsp_ticket_hist  
    ORDER
       BY ID DESC 
    LIMIT 1 
 ) 
ON fsp_issue_log.ISSUE_SERIAL_NUM = fsp_ticket_hist.TICKET_SN
";
```

Comment: Provide sample data and expected output.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try with:

```
select fsp_issue_log.ISSUE_SERIAL_NUM , fsp_issue_log.STATUS, fsp_issue_log.DATECREATED, fsp_issue_log.ASSIGNEDTO, fsp_issue_log.ORG
 , fsp_issue_log.SEVERITY
 , fsp_issue_log.DESCRIPTION
 , fsp_ticket_hist.COMMENTS
FROM fsp_ticket_hist 
INNER JOIN fsp_issue_log ON fsp_issue_log.ISSUE_SERIAL_NUM = fsp_ticket_hist.TICKET_SN
GROUP BY fsp_ticket_hist.ID
ORDER BY fsp_ticket_hist.ID DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: What i basically want is to join two tables together(but i want the join table to return only one record, i.e (SELECT COMMENTS FROM fsp_ticket_hist ORDER BY ID DESC  LIMIT 1 ): when this querry fires, let it join it  ON fsp_issue_log.ISSUE_SERIAL_NUM = fsp_ticket_hist.TICKET_SN..Such that the returned records will be fsp_issue_log.ISSUE_SERIAL_NUM , fsp_issue_log.STATUS, fsp_issue_log.DATECREATED, fsp_issue_log.ASSIGNEDTO, fsp_issue_log.ORG
 , fsp_issue_log.SEVERITY
 , fsp_issue_log.DESCRIPTION
 , fsp_ticket_hist.COMMENTS